# JavaScript: поиск по HTML data-атрибутам JSON

Tags: javascript, html5

В Javascript есть переменная, куда записаны данные в формате JSON:

```
var json_test2 = {"a":  "2", "b": "2"};
var a = json_test2.a;
var b = json_test2.b;
```

Мне нужно исходя из значений, либо `a`, либо `b`, либо по json строке в целом найти соответствующий блок  в HTML (чтобы вывести содержимое блока):

```
<div data-number='{"a":  "1", "b": "1"}'>Test1</div>
<div data-number='{"a":  "2", "b": "2"}'>Test2</div>
<div data-number='{"a":  "3", "b": "3"}'>Test3</div>
```

Как это можно сделать с помощью JavaScript (без jQuery)?

Comment: Ну пробегитесь по всему дереву элементов и по атрибуту `data-number` найдите нужный. В чём проблема? Где код на js, который у вас не получается?

Comment: @ArchDemon, Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли получить по определенному атрибуту? Почему-то не работает:  `document.querySelector('div[data-number ="{"a":  "2", "b": "2"}]')`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var json_test2 = {"a":  "2", "b": "2"};
var a = json_test2.a;
var b = json_test2.b;
document.querySelectorAll('[data-number=\'{"a":  "'+a+'", "b": "'+b+'"}\']')[0].innerHTML="Блок найден";
```

```html
<div data-number='{"a":  "1", "b": "1"}'>Test1</div>
<div data-number='{"a":  "2", "b": "2"}'>Test2</div>
<div data-number='{"a":  "3", "b": "3"}'>Test3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Например так можно...

```js
    function go()
    {    
    var json_test2 = {"a":  "2", "b": "2"};
    var a = json_test2.a;
    var b = json_test2.b;
    var input = document.getElementById(a + '.' + b).innerHTML;
    console.log(input);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="1.1">Test1</div>
    <div id="2.2">Test2</div>
    <div id="3.3">Test3</div>
    <div onclick="go();">go</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но div блоки должны быть как в примере